# How to make an alias not immediately execute

Tags: shell, zsh, alias

I'm adding some aliases to my .zshrc file and wondering if I can add an alias that doesn't execute immediately?

Example of usage I want:
I want to be able to have an alias for creating a new git branch
Ideally I can type the alias `gcb` which will output `git checkout -b` in the terminal and doesn't execute, then I can add the new branch name and hit enter.

*Note:*
I know I can do the following:
`command alias_name` to prevent the alias immediately executing, but I'm seeking a way to do this without the command keyword as having to type that extra text almost defeats the purpose of the alias shortcut

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean is that you want the interactive command-line editor to be populated with the expansion result? I don't know zsh, but bash definitely has features for that (maybe not with aliases, but that can be accessed through a function for sure).

Comment: (in bash, at least, aliases are generally considered a misfeature that shouldn't be used; they're _much_ less flexible and capable than shell functions).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/1514569. You don't need to hit enter, but rather Control-x a to expand an alias to its definition.

Comment: @Tamjid : A command such as `alias foo=bar` immediatelty **defines** the alias _foo_. If you later enter the command _foo x y_, the alias is in effect and the command _bar x y_ is run instead.

Comment: @user1934428 ahh, thanks seems like i'll be using this

Comment: If you no longer need your question answered, then please close your question.

Comment: @user1934428 if you add your comment as a answer i will accept it

Comment: @Tamjid : Comment posted as an answer. I was at first reluctant to write _this_ as an answer, because it looked so obvious to me that I didn't expect such an answer to be generally useful....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definition

```
alias foo=bar
```

immediately defines the alias foo in the current zsh process. If you later type

```
foo x y
```

the command `bar x y` is executed. Note that by definition of zsh, this behaviour only works in *interactive* shells. If you want to exploit this in a shell *script*, you have to enable alias expansion explicitly.